# How to create user accounts for existing employees in Odoo 15?

Tags: odoo, odoo-15, odoo-16

In odoo 15 i have to create users for existing employees. so is there any way to create it from existing employee instead of I create users and then from HR Setting i select Related User.
so how I can create all employees to users in odoo?

Comment: There is no option in Odoo out of the box for creating user from employee but you can from Related User in employee form to enter the name and if not exists you can create it using "Create" or "Create and Edit" option. If you need to create users for all employees at once you need to develop your custom addons.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using Automated Action in the settings.

- Go to Settings > Automated Actions.
- Create a new action.
- Enter Employee as the related model.
- Select on create.
- Also select create new record as an action
- Edit data to write to enter the details. You may need to give the reference or the python code.

When saved it will create a new user automatically. You can stack more actions and triggers together as well.

Here is the [Odoo Documentation page](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/16.0/applications/productivity/studio/automated_actions.html) for v16.